# jquery mobile 1.3.1 padding-top incorrectly calculated on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, padding, pageload

I've been googling this for days and although there are many similar threads the answer still eludes me. I have pared the problem down to this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-id="myHeader" data-theme="none" data-position="fixed">
        <img src="images/my1200x150logo.jpg"/>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <p>Content line 1</p>
    <p>Content line 2</p>
    <p>Content line 3</p>
    <p>Content line 4</p>
    <p>Content line 5</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-id="myFooter" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed"> 
  <h4>My footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

I am trying to achieve a RWD effect with the logo image resizing to fit the page. This all works perfectly except for the initial page load, which sets padding-top to zero in the jqm updatePagePadding routine causing the content to flow up under the image.

I understand that images load hours after the js is run and this is a common issue. Any event such as a page resize causes the padding to be updated correctly.

So my question is, how can I force JQM to call updatePagePadding **after** my image(s) have finished loading ?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery pageshow event ? [link to the API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)

Basically jquery will fire an event after the page is loaded, and the elements are ready you can wait for that event and then call you function, example:

```
$("#pageID").on("pageshow",function(){
   updatePagePadding();
});
```

Also check this for complete reference on what events are binded to every jquery mobile page, [page widget API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/page/)

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I put the script in the head section, it is never executed. If I put it at the end of the body section, I get ReferenceError: updatePagePadding is not defined

Comment: you can not put script in head, jquery mobile does not load head tag, it loads head tag only on index.html, other pages put your javascript inside <div data-role="page"></div>

Comment: Sorry for being thick. I've read elsewhere to put the jquery and jquery.mobile scripts in the head tag. I did as you suggest and now get $ undefined. Would you mind posting the page structure I should be using to achieve what I want within the context of my example ? So that everything loads in the correct order ? I really appreciate your help.